# How to combine filer and sortArray on stage project in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework

hi guys i need some help, i want to make some projection on specific field, but inside the projection stage i want also make a filter based on some condition and make a sorting.
this is aggregation

```
[
{
    '$match': {
        '_id': ObjectId('659dfebd24358fa4604510bb')
    }
}, {
    '$project': {
        'date': 1, 
        'serviceScheduleId': 1, 
        'serviceId': 1, 
        'branchOfficeId': 1, 
        'companyId': 1, 
        'queue': {
            '$filter': {
                'input': '$queue', 
                'cond': {
                    '$and': [
                        {
                            '$eq': [
                                '$$this.queueType', 'online'
                            ]
                        }, {
                            '$eq': [
                                '$$this.checkinTime', None
                            ]
                        }, {
                            '$eq': [
                                '$$this.user.status', 'incall'
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }, 
            '$sortArray': {
                'input': '$queue', 
                'sortBy': {
                    'user.ticketInt': -1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    '$group': {
        '_id': '$_id', 
        'items': {
            '$push': '$queue'
        }
    }
}, {
    '$unwind': {
        'path': '$queue'
    }
}
```

]

and this is my mongodb playground
https://mongoplayground.net/p/WNnSOzQKUJB

when i excecute thet code on mongodb compas it show some error like this

> Invalid $project :: caused by :: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'. Consider using $getField or $setField.

Comment: You can't do it together. Create another `$set`/`$project` stage, and set the field with the `$sortArray`

Comment: @YongShun
If I add 2 project stages, will it affect the database performance?

Comment: You may read this [article](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#projection-optimization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the field with the prefix: `$` as the field name.

**Approach 1: Create another `$set` / `$project` stage**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  // Match stage,
  {
    "$project": {
      "date": 1,
      "serviceScheduleId": 1,
      "serviceId": 1,
      "branchOfficeId": 1,
      "companyId": 1,
      "queue": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$queue",
          "cond": {
            "$and": [
              {
                "$eq": [
                  "$$this.queueType",
                  "online"
                ]
              },
              {
                "$eq": [
                  "$$this.checkinTime",
                  null
                ]
              },
              {
                "$eq": [
                  "$$this.user.status",
                  "incall"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      queue: {
        "$sortArray": {
          "input": "$queue",
          "sortBy": {
            "user.ticketInt": -1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo (Approach 1) @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/s2M9gL0Zk_f)

**Approach 2: Place the `$filter` operator in `input` field of `$sortArray`**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  // Match stage,
  {
    "$project": {
      "date": 1,
      "serviceScheduleId": 1,
      "serviceId": 1,
      "branchOfficeId": 1,
      "companyId": 1,
      "queue": {
        "$sortArray": {
          "input": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$queue",
              "cond": {
                "$and": [
                  {
                    "$eq": [
                      "$$this.queueType",
                      "online"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "$eq": [
                      "$$this.checkinTime",
                      null
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "$eq": [
                      "$$this.user.status",
                      "incall"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "sortBy": {
            "user.ticketInt": -1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo (Approach 2) @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wH32xzsvJds)

Comment: alhamdulillah, thanks mr @youngshun, you lighten my day